# PHP preg_match yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, regex

I need some help with a regular expressions. I'm trying to validate if a string looks like 'yyyy-mm-dd', this is my code so far:

```
case "date":
                if (preg_match("/^[0-9\-]/i",$value)){
                    $date = explode("-",$value);
                    $year = $date[0];
                    $month = $date[1];
                    $day = $date[2];
                    if (!checkdate($month,$day,$year))
                    {
                        $this->errors[] = "Ogiltigt datum.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Ogiltigt datum angivet.";
                }
            break;
```

I am very new to regular expressions, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? Will you allow 9999-99-99 as well? Or are you looking to see if a date is valid or not?

Comment: Yes, I'm just making sure it looks like a correct date, then I explode it and validate it using checkdate(), which take everything in consideration, leap years etc.

Comment: The top answer is for you then. Good luck :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex to check date is in YYYY-MM-DD format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\z/', $value) ) { ...
```

however this kind of pattern can validate something like `0000-40-99`

pattern details:

```
/         # pattern delimiter
^         # anchor: start of the string
[0-9]{4}  # four digits
-         # literal: -
[0-9]{2}
-
[0-9]{2}
\z        # anchor: end of the string
/         # pattern delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks that works great, but could anyone explain why? I'd like to know why and how it works, thanks.

Comment: @PetterPettersson: `[0-9]` = any character between 0 to 9. `{4}` previous character class (0 to 9) 4 times. `-` dash, and so on. See https://www.debuggex.com/r/iDL-oQxvjyTC2AhF

Comment: @PetterPettersson: I added a description of the pattern, however keep in mind that this use only very basic regex notions. I suggest you to read a tutorial about regex, for example: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. I will use your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [capturing group](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), you don't need call `explode`.

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/', $value, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[1];
    $month = $matches[2];
    $day = $matches[3];
    ...
}
```

- `\d` matches any digit characters.
- `{n}` is quantifier: to match previous pattern exactly 4 times.
- You can access the matched group using `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]`, ...

  - `$matches[0]` contains entire matched string.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I never thought about the $matches thing, it worked great as well.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use regex one can also use a simple function to validate the date according to the Swedish format (yyyy-mm-dd) or any other format for that matter.

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

var_dump(validateDate('2014-01-11', 'Y-m-d')); // true
var_dump(validateDate('2014-1-11', 'Y-m-d')); // false
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: Yes, but this is the function I'm building to use for validating dates.

Comment: @PetterPettersson I'm just saying that you can validate the format and the date using only one function.