# php confirmation messages during form's submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, popup

I've created a form which I want to validate by clicking a submit button and, if everything is ok, store the inputs in a DB. Both the validation and the storing in the DB work fine. I've put, also, for the user's convenience, two popups, one for a successful submission and one when an error occurs.

My problem is that when I load for the first time the page in which my form is, I receive the same popup as when the validation is proper and the data have been submitted correctly.

Could you please help me? I want these popups to be appeared only after the pressing of the submit button.

Here is my php code that does that:

**Code for validation**

```
<?php  
    $firstNameError = $lastNameError = $streetError = $cityError = $postcodeError = $emailError = $mobileNumberError = $dateError = "";
    $firstName = $lastName = $street = $city = $postcode = $email = $mobileNumber = $date = $comments = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        if (empty($_POST["firstName"]))
            {$firstNameError = "Please fill this field";}
            else
            {
                $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName))
                {
                    $firstNameError = "Please use only letters and white spaces";
                }
            }
            if (empty($_POST["lastName"]))
            {$lastNameError = "Please fill this field";}
            else
            {
                $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName))
                {
                    $lastNameError = "Please use only letters and white spaces"; 
                }
            }   
            if (empty($_POST["street"]))
            {$streetError = "Please fill this field";}
            else 
            {
                // check if street address syntax is valid
                $street = test_input($_POST["street"]);
                if(!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $street)){
                    $streetError = "Please use only letters, numbers and whitespaces";
                }
            }   
            if (empty($_POST["city"]))
            {$cityError = "Please fill this field";}
            else
            {
                // check if city syntax is valid
                $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
                // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city))
                {
                    $cityError = "Please use only letters and whitespaces"; 
                }
            }
            if (empty($_POST["postcode"]))
            {$postcodeError = "Please fill this field";}
            else 
            {
                //check if postcode syntax is valid
                $postcode = test_input($_POST["postcode"]);
                if(!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*$/', $postcode)){
                    $postcodeError = "Please use only letters, numbers and whitespace";
                }
            }
            if (empty($_POST["email"]))
            {$emailError = "Please fill this field";}
            else
            {
                $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
                if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
                {
                    $emailError = "Please rewrite your email address in the format a@b.code"; 
                }
            }
            if (empty($_POST["mobileNumber"]))
            {$mobileNumberError = "Please fill this field";}
            else 
            {
                $mobileNumber = test_input($_POST["mobileNumber"]);
                // check if mobile number syntax is valid
                if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/',$mobileNumber))
                {
                    $mobileNumberError = "Please write only numbers";
                }
            }
            if (empty($_POST["date"]))
            {$dateError = "Please fill this field";}
            else
            {
                $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
                //modified based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format
                if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date))
                {
                    $dateError = "Please follow this format:yyyy-mm-dd";
                }
            }
            $comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
    }
    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }   
?>
```

**Code for storing in DB**

```
<?php
    if (empty($firstNameError) && empty($lastNameError) && empty($streetError) && empty($cityError) && empty($postcodeError) && empty($emailError) && empty($mobileNumberError) && empty($dateError)){
    mysql_connect("ServerName", "username", "password") or die("Connect failed!");
    mysql_select_db("DbName") or die(mysql_error());
    $appointment = "INSERT INTO inquiries 
                 (submit_date, first_name, last_name, address, postcode, email, phone, wedding_date, wedding_location, special_req) 
                 VALUES 
                 ('$currentDate', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$street', '$postcode', '$email', '$mobileNumber', '$date', '$city', '$comments')              ";              
    $result = mysql_query($appointment) or die(mysql_error());
    $message = "Your details have been submitted successfully. We will contact you soon!";
            echo "<script>
            alert('$message');
        </script>";
        }
           else{
        $message = "Oooops! Something went wrong. Please, resubmit the form based on the indications appeared under each field.";
        echo "<script>
            alert('$message');
        </script>";
        }
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your line

```
if (empty($firstNameError) && empty($lastNameError) && empty($streetError) && empty($cityError) && empty($postcodeError) && empty($emailError) && empty($mobileNumberError) && empty($dateError)){
```

Should be done checking for not empty

```
if (!empty($firstNameError) && !empty($lastNameError) && !empty($streetError) && !empty($cityError).....
```

Otherwise the script will proceed to the query

Comment: Hello and thx for your quick response! I applied your proposition, but I am now getting the second message I've set ("Oooops! Something went wrong. Please, resubmit the form based on the indications appeared under each field."). Did I miss something?