# Date format validation in php

Tags: php, validation, date, date-format

I made a form with 3 fields and one of them is date of birth. I want to check that date is in format of `yyyy-mm-dd` . So far I managed to do this:

Check `$_POST` vars are set, exit if any missing.

```
if(!isset($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["surname"]) || !isset($_POST["date_of_birth"]))
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
    die($output);
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$name       = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$surname       = filter_var($_POST["surname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$date_of_birth    = filter_var($_POST["date_of_birth"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$date_regex = '/^(19|20)\d\d[\-\/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\-\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/';
$date = '2013-04-14';

//additional php validation
if(strlen($name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($surname)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Surname is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if (!preg_match($date_regex, $date)) //check entered data is numbers
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Only yyyy-mm-dd format is allowed'));
    die($output);
}
```

The problem is that when it comes to validating date I always get an error saying I entered bad date format even if I enter it correctly. Could you please help me by telling where I made a mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format

Comment: You have an extra comma `if (!preg_match($date_regex, $date, ))` Remove the stray comma after `$date`, or give it a variable to put the number of matches in.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$date = '2013-04-14';
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) 
echo 'correct';
else
echo 'incorrect';
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but effect is same, still getting error.

Comment: cause you are matching wrong date format YYYY-dd-mm you need to change your $date format to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Corrected it, but still no go

Comment: Nope still northing, I'm beginning to assume that  mistake is not in validation, but somewhere else in code cause i tried every possible code with preg_match and none solved this

Comment: $date = '2013-14-04'; ?

Comment: you need to check line by line your code post your form code also

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    $date = "2014-05-06";
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) == $date) print_r('valid');
```