# How to check the inputted date in the form is in yyyy-mm-dd format or not in core php?

Tags: php

This is my form to add a job.

```
<form action="adminindex.php?page=add_job" method="post">

    <label>Job Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title">

    <label>Opening</label>
    <input type="number" name="opening">

    <label>Deadline</label>
    <input type="text" name="deadline" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

</form>
```

Now, how can I check whether the inputted date in the form is in the form yyyy-mm-dd or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this link:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

```
$date="2012-09-12";

if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date))
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

You can use different regex to match your requirements XXXX-XX-XX like this:

```
  preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/");
```

would match the given string for four numbers - two numbers - two numbers (almost yyyy-mm-dd). But you can do even more with more complex expressions.

Here's a test for the regex above:

```
23-03-2012 // false
1987-12-24 // true
22-03-1981 // false
0000-00-00 // true
```

Do check the link below for regex cheat sheet:

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: The OP wants a solution in PHP, not javascript

Comment: I realized that now! Thanks! editing it!

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the date supplied with PHP's interpretation of that input using `strtotime`.

```
$date_format = 'Y-m-d';
$input = '2009-03-03';

$input = trim($input); // remove any spaces around the date
$time = strtotime($input);

if(date($date_format, $time) == $input)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful

[PHP:checkdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

You can use `bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )` and it will output true if the date is vaild

Quote From PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump(checkdate(12, 31, 2000));
var_dump(checkdate(2, 29, 2001));
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```