# scrape data with simplehtmldom without div's after a <br> tag

Tags: html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

How can i get to the 3 line and only extract the time?

```
<BR>
<BR>UTC=2016-10-12  15:03:58.042 Wed
<BR> LT=2016-10-12  17:03:58.042 Wed (Summer)
<BR>Country/Timezone=+1d (Berlin,Brussels,Paris) ,UTC=60 min.
<BR>Summertime from 25 Mar 01:00, Wintertime from 25 Oct 01:00 (UTC)
```

So the desired output would be: 17:03:58.042

I am trying to do this with Simple html dom

This displays all the text.
I'm trying to find the right selector but the data i want isn't between a div.
It's just 
Anyone who knows how to select the correct line?

```
<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://10.20.83.1/status.htm');

// extract text from HTML
echo $html->plaintext;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Extracting the text.**

Perhaps use:

`// Find all text blocks
$es = $html->find('text');`

From http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart

NB: If the wanted text-block is always the second one, you can use it like:

`// Find all text blocks
$es = $html->find('text', 2);`

**2. Validating or interpreting the date by format.**

I've once written a small php function to guess some datetime values by formats.
See this: http://pastebin.com/DrYwdU2D

You could use a regular expression to do the same thing if you prefer:
[PHP Regex to check date is in YYYY-MM-DD format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)

Hope it helps.