# Validation for date and time in format d/m/Y-H:i:s?

Tags: php, regex, validation, date, time

Just looking to validate the following date 07/03/2017-15:54:42 to ensure that this format has been used but can't find a regex that works

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which takes string and format string, and if methods returned FALSE, you can check [DateTime::getLastErrors](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getlasterrors.php). It has some advantages over using regexp - it can check leap years and all other date abnormalities.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and not accurate way is to use a regex like the following:

```
/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

It will simply validate that the string has a correct number of digits separated by some slashes, colons and a dash. A more complex approach to building a regex is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format). You can take it and add your own part for time validation, but use the patterns for a four digit year, a pattern for the month format and date format.

A more reliable way is to try and create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from your string:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y-H:i:s', '17/03/2017-15:54:42')
/* DateTime {#173
     +"date": "2017-03-17 15:54:42.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Jerusalem",
   }
*/
```

If you try it with a wrong string, you'll get `false` result:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y-H:i:s', '17.03/2017-15:54:42')
// false
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are asking for could be something like that:

```
(\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}-(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}
```

However using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) has advantages [as exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651577/7666764) by [Wax Cage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319995/wax-cage)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the mentioned reference?