# date parsing the right date from unknown format

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I'm extracting dates from documents. The dates are varying in format, from American to European and from dashes to backslashes.

```
$d1 = '03/12/2017';
$d2 = '12/03/2017';
$d3 = '26/03/2017';


Carbon::parse($d1)->toDateString(); // the month is read as March but it should be read as December
Carbon::parse($d2)->toDateString(); // the month is read as December but it should be March
Carbon::parse($d2)->toDateString(); // throws an ErrorException failing to parse the time due to incorrect format
```

The problem is not knowing if the date is in d/m/Y or m/d/Y which results in sorting the documents by the wrong month.

These documents are coming from different businesses around the world and I have no control over the date format.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: How can you tell whether `03/12/2017` means the 12th of March of 3rd of December?

Comment: read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194322/php-regex-to-check-date-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format

Comment: If there is no other information that will tell you which format the date is in then there is no solution to this problem (unless you consider defaulting to one of the formats as a solution). If you can tell which country the data came from then might this confirm the format?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil that's the problem, isn't?

Comment: American format is `MM/DD/YYYY`, which is why its interpreted as December and March, and not March and December. You should use `YYYY-MM-DD`, that is unmistakable.

Comment: @AndyG I was thinking of this but some documents will still fail, as the country sometimes can't be established.

Comment: You could process all the dates where the format can be confidently established. Then you are left with a set of values to consider. What will you do with them? Discard them, leaving the field empty? This would be better than having incorrect, misleading, values in the data source. (I suppose you could have an additional field confirming that the field-value is likely to be wrong: this is not a good idea as it still remains very easy to mistakenly assume the date is correct.)

Comment: @lesandru: It indeed is. My comment was to point you to understanding that for certain dates you cannot decide, unless you have been given more information about the structure. You could try to infer the format from the context of the document, but that is not something you would want to do programatically.

Comment: To summarize, if you do not have confidence in a value, then don't store it.

Comment: thank you for the quick feedback guys, unfortunately, I haven't thought about this when I started the project, 2 months of work gone just because of this, I can't believe it

Answer (score 1):

You should use `createFromFormat` See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

```
Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y",$datestring)
```

This way you define how the string should be interpreted, if you know what the input string will be.

Carbon extends php's [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class so you might also read up on the DateTime createFromFormat docs at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php